# OmniFaces CombinedResourceHandler takes long time to load

Tags: jsf, caching, omnifaces, bootsfaces, combinedresourcehandler

I use OmniFaces 2.2 togehter with PrimeFaces 5.3 and BootsFaces 0.8.1. Since it is recomended to use `CombinedResourceHandler` with BootsFaces I tried to use first as per BootsFaces instructions: http://showcase.bootsfaces.net/integration/OmniFaces.jsf

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.COMBINED_RESOURCE_ACTIVATE_RESOURCE_CACHING</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.CACHE_SETTING_APPLICATION_MAX_CAPACITY</param-name>
    <param-value>30</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.CACHE_SETTING_APPLICATION_TTL</param-name>
    <param-value>86400</param-value>
</context-param>
```

In my application I use my own JS libary and own CSS stuff inside the `<h:head>` of my layout/template XHTML.

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="custom.css"/>
<h:outputScript library="scripts" name="js/custom_scripts.js" target="head"/>
```

The `CombinedResourceHandler` is enabled inside the `faces-config`. The application is in `Production` mode and on every reload on every page the pageload takes much time to download the combined css and js files as you can see in the attached image:

[image: Pageload]

So the whole pageload is double to three times higher than without the `CombinedResourceHandler`. The only thing I can imagine is that I am using it completely wrong. But where is my failure?

Comment: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CombinedResourceHandler documentation says to use `org.omnifaces.COMBINED_RESOURCE_HANDLER_CACHE_TTL`. Replace all those params with it. Where exactly did you get them from?

Comment: @BalusC i got it from here http://showcase.bootsfaces.net/integration/OmniFaces.jsf

Comment: Oh, that's only applicable when you manually modify OmniFaces as per their instructions. This is not necessary anymore since it has been added to OmniFaces 2.1 (and improved/simplified so that it requires only 1 param).

Comment: Ah okay. Jep i replaced it. Now it works much better :) Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those context parameters are not correct. Those are only applicable when you modify OmniFaces 2.0 as per [BootsFaces own instructions](http://showcase.bootsfaces.net/integration/OmniFaces.jsf).

Since OmniFaces 2.1, the solution was integrated as per [issue 100](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/100) and code and configuration have been simplified so that only the below context parameter is necessary in order to enable combined resource handler cache:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.COMBINED_RESOURCE_HANDLER_CACHE_TTL</param-name>
    <param-value>86400</param-value>
</context-param>
```

See also the documentation on the [`CombinedResourceHandler` showcase](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CombinedResourceHandler).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. We're going to update our BootsFaces showcase as soon as possible. As you, @BalusC, pointed out, our instructions work if you follow all of them - but there are obviously confusing.